# Survival Data optimal cutoff point for 2 indendent semiquantitative markers

Tags: pca, survival

so I am trying to find a visualization for the Independent predictors of a: a traditional metric marker for mortality b: a markerset (represented by ordinal 1,2,3) for mortality

The Analysis set has already been grouped for cutoff Points on the traditional metric marker(the study wants to Show traditional marker plus new marker set very good predictors)

and my Approach,job is it, to justify the metric marker cutoff. Therefor I think that a reasonable Approach is it to use a surival object for death and Survival time dependent on some sort of PCA here, can anyone suggest an idea?

BEst wishes

Comment: Never mind, I guess I was way off, solved it with a grouped logistic regression and confidence intervals, PCA was not part of the deal, but should have been? More accurately factor analysis?